error when switching to Ubuntu now can not use computer
I had dual booted with Ubunto 22.04.04 and when went to restart after uploading ubunto from usb I got these error messages “sgx disabled by bios” I posted screenshot at bottom of post. I then tried to go to use windows and when enter my pin it says “this device is offline please use another method”. I took photos of settings also (posted at bottom), in case I need correct some of those. Please let me know what need do, I need get computer working again asap as use it for work tomorrow. I am new to programming and just started The Oden Project.
I am also Ok to wipe my computer as its a new laptop with no files I need on there. I tried to wipe it from the windows screen and it gave me an error.




As written there is no info here to offer any help. What version of Ubuntu? How was the boot media made? How was the install done? Exact steps for at least these 3 things need to be added to the question.

please take the [tour], read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

@DavidDE ok just added that info. The boot media was made with Rufus

in GRUB, go to advanced option for Ubuntu, and try booting an older kernel. If it works, fully update the system.

You should always be able to boot Windows in UEFI mode directly  via the EFI menu (some key at power-on to allow you to select device or os to boot).

@ubfan1 it lets me do that but when go to enter my pin on windows says its offline and glitches
